# Can anyone identify this strange number?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm building a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013. One of the steps is going to trigger another workflow. The workflow is published and works correctly but there is an anomaly that I've never seen before:

[image]

Does anyone know what the {5} is next to the 'Get Site Info' workflow title?

Comment: what action did you use for "Start Get Site Info {5} with"? Do you have more than one actions about "Get Site Info" action in your site's workflows.

Comment: 'Get Site Info' is a 2010 workflow which I am triggering from inside this workflow. The action used here is 'Start a List Workflow' and it is the only time that get Site Info is mentioned in this workflow.

Comment: in my test, it could work well, there is no {number} added into the action. Could you create a new sharepoint 2013 workflow and test again? Also, please test if this issue occurs on other lists/libaries.